# Foreach loop trouble while trying to edit a csv export file with powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

I am complete newbie in the IT world but having the following question: I am exporting users from AD based on some criteria (code is messy but works). When I export the CSV file before the foreach section it all works well, but then I need to add 9 as a digit in front of all lines which start with 0 in my joined column for extensionattribute 1 and 2. I am trying to import the CSV file and then export it again edited.

The code:

```
$cost = @{Name="Cost";Expression={$_.extensionattribute1,$_.extensionattribute2 -join ''}}
$id = @{Name="SAP ID";Expression={$_.samaccountname}}



get-aduser -properties samaccountname,co,extensionattribute1,extensionattribute2 -filter {(co -eq "Dxxxx") -and (enabled -eq "true") -and (samaccountname -like "1*" -or samaccountname -like "2*" -or samaccountname -like "3*")} | select $id,$cost | export-csv C:\Users\xxxx\Favorites\CCDxxx.csv -notypeinformation -encoding UTF8



$csv = import-csv C:\Users\xxxx\Favorites\CCDxxx.csv



$var = foreach($line in $csv){


if($cost -like "0*"){
$newcost = "9"+$cost
write-host $sam ";" $newcost}




if($cost -notlike "0*"){
$newcost = $cost
write-host $sam ";" $cost}


}



$var | export-csv C:\Users\xxxx\Favorites\CCxxx1.csv -notypeinformation -encoding UTF8
```

The script will run but my lack of knowledge exports nothing. Any help will be highly appreciated.

P.S. Forgive me if I asked my question out of the high standards you have here, but I will learn. Thank you,
Regards.

Comment: Note that, using `ScriptBlock` based filters for AD Cmdlets even tho it _might work_ is not really supported. You should use __query string__ as recommended by Microsoft. As an example of what can happen when using `ScriptBlock`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70126195/replacing-a-string-with-a-variable/70126347#70126347

Answer (score 3):

You need to refer to each object being enumerated in your `foreach` loop in order to inspect and update its `.cost` property:

```sh
if($line.cost -like "0*"){ 
  # ...
  $line.cost = ...
}
```

Your loop needn't produce output (no need for `$var = ...`), as you can simply use `$csv` as the input to the 2nd `Export-Csv` call, given that `$csv` after the loop contains the *modified* objects.<sup>[1]</sup>

However, you can streamline your code by using only a *single* pipeline in which you transform the `Get-ADUser` output objects as desired with the help of a [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) call, in whose script block (`{ ... }`) you can use the [automatic `$_` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_) to refer to the input object at hand. In lieu of [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) with calculated properties, you can construct the desired output objects with a `[pscustomobject]` literal.

```sh
get-aduser -properties samaccountname,co,extensionattribute1,extensionattribute2 -filter {(co -eq "Dxxxx") -and (enabled -eq "true") -and (samaccountname -like "1*" -or samaccountname -like "2*" -or samaccountname -like "3*")} | 
  ForEach-Object {
    $cost = $_.extensionattribute1, $_.extensionattribute2 -join ''
    if ($cost -notlike '0*') { $cost = '9' + $cost }
    # Create and output a custom object with the desired properties.
    [pscustomobject] @{
      Cost = $cost
      'SAP ID' = $_.samaccountname
    }
  } | 
    export-csv C:\Users\xxxx\Favorites\CCDxxx.csv -notypeinformation -encoding UTF8
```

---

<sup>[1] `[pscustomobject]` is a .NET *reference type*, which means that the `$csv` array contains *references* to `[pscustomobject]` instances, so that later modifications of the properties of these instances are also reflected in the array.</sup>