# How add information from another Powershell output

Tags: powershell

I need some help.

For example, i need to get some information from AD computer.I use something like this:

```
$computers=Get-ADComputer -Filter {enabled -eq "true"} -Properties name,IPv4Address,OperatingSystem | Select-Object name,created,IPv4Address,OperatingSystem
```

Then, i do somethig with this computers:

```
Invoke-Command -computername $computers.name -ScriptBlock {get-hotfix -Description security*} -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue| select-object pscomputername,hotfixid
```

But i dont understand, how can i merge information from AD and my output. For example i need to get out string or file like that:

Computername(from AD), OperatingSystem (from AD), hotfixid (from my invoke command)

Thx

Comment: How about a *calculated property*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would personally do something like this, using [`Group-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object?view=powershell-7.2) to get a [`hashtable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.hashtable?view=net-6.0) for lookup, where the *Keys* are the computer's **`Name`** (`PSComputerName`) property. Doing this would improve the execution time of your script.

One thing to note, I would advise you against using a *script block* `{ ... }` on the `-Filter` parameter of the ActiveDirectory Module Cmdlets. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70126195/replacing-a-string-with-a-variable/70126347#70126347) as an example of things that can happen.

```
$params = @{
    Filter = "Enabled -eq '$true'"
    Properties = "IPv4Address", "OperatingSystem"
}
$computers = Get-ADComputer @params

$map = Invoke-Command $computers.Name -ScriptBlock {
    Get-Hotfix -Description security*
} -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
Group-Object PSComputerName -AsHashTable -AsString

$outObject = {
    param($computer, $id)

    [pscustomobject]@{
        Name = $computer.Name
        IPv4Address = $computer.IPv4Address
        OperatingSystem = $computer.OperatingSystem
        HotFixID = $id
    }
}

foreach($computer in $computers)
{   
    if(-not ($hotfix = $map[$computer.Name]))
    {
        & $outObject -computer $computer -id $null
        continue
    }

    foreach($id in $hotfix.HotFixID)
    {
        & $outObject -computer $computer -id $id
    }
}
```

---

Note that, [`Get-HotFix`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-hotfix?view=powershell-7.2#example-2--get-hotfixes-from-multiple-computers-filtered-by-a-string) has a `[-ComputerName <String[]>]` parameter, untested but in this case, `Invoke-Command` might not be needed.

Answer (score 1):

Using -pv or -pipelinevariable.  But then invoke-command won't run in parallel unless you use foreach-object -parallel in powershell 7.

```
get-adcomputer a002 -property operatingsystem -pv comp | 
  % { invoke-command $_.name { get-hotfix } } | 
  select pscomputername, @{n='OperatingSystem';e={$comp.operatingsystem}}, hotfixid

PSComputerName OperatingSystem       HotFixID
-------------- ---------------       --------
A002           Windows 10 Enterprise KB5006365
A002           Windows 10 Enterprise KB4562830
A002           Windows 10 Enterprise KB4570334
```

ps 7

```
get-adcomputer a002 -property operatingsystem -pv comp | 
  % -parallel { invoke-command $_.name { get-hotfix } } | 
  select pscomputername, @{n='OperatingSystem';e={$comp.operatingsystem}}, hotfixid
```