# Active Directory query include group name part of members list

Tags: powershell

I want to list the active directory name  starting with prefix and its members.

`Get-ADGroup` gives me list of group names I wanted. for the `Get-ADGroupMember` command output I want to include group name, then list of members.

tried this code, but its giving me the error `$_.Name`.  How do we include group name part of `Get-ADGroupMember` output?

```
Get-ADGroup -filter { name -like 'Test_*'  -and GroupCategory -eq 'Security' } |
 select-object -first 2  |ForEach-Object {
 Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $_.Name | select $_.name,Name
 }
```

Thanks

Comment: Please post the error message in its entirety

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`select $_.name,Name` is a syntactical error, you need to use a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.2#example-11--create-calculated-properties-for-each-inputobject) to define the new property name and value:

```
$calculatedProps = @(
    @{
        Name = 'GroupName'
        Expression = { $groupName }
    }
    @{
        Name = 'Members'
        Expression = { $_.Name }
    }
)

Get-ADGroup -Filter "name -like 'Test_*' -and GroupCategory -eq 'Security'" |
    Select-Object -First 2 | ForEach-Object {
        $groupName = $_.Name

        Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $_.DistinguishedName |
            Select-Object $calculatedProps
    }
```

I would also recommend you to stop using *script blocks* on the `-Filter` parameter of the AD Module cmdlets to avoid future problems. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70126347/15339544) is one example of the issues it might bring.

Comment: @sfgroups happy to help, if the answer was helpful please consider accepting it